# what is the easiest way to build a custom distro with specific installs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, live-cd, distribution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to create a custom linux distribution](https://serverfault.com/questions/215628/easiest-way-to-create-a-custom-linux-distribution)

I did see this post:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/215628/easiest-way-to-create-a-custom-linux-distribution

And wanted to know if there is a new process for this?

Also I wanted to know if I could pre-install select packages?

Say I want a LAMP server but with PostgreSQL instead of MySQL and I want several Python packages as well as some custom code.

I think Ubuntu would be my choice for the OS if that makes a difference.

Looking for:

- tools
- tutorials
- any help at all...

Thanks in advance.

BTW This would be my first attempt at something like this

Comment: What is your purpose?  Very rarely is a "custom Linux distribution" what you really want/need...

Comment: I'm trying to make an install of a specific server ready to deploy/run out of the box with no additional setup needed. I have a Python project I'm working on but the initial server setup is a pain. Other are working on similar projects with the same base server. Wanted to create the basic server as a distro for others to us and speed up development time. So my hopes are to create a distro with all the options/packages/scripts/etc... installed for the community to use as a starting point and hopefully speed up the development process

Comment: I thought the question might get closed as it's very similar to the link I provided in the question itself, but I was hoping to keep it open as it's more of a custom solution for a group of developers and not a distro that many outside of the project would use.

Comment: Is this all for environments you will be controlling? If so you may want to look at deployment tools (puppet, chef, radmind) and/or VirtualBox appliances instead of rolling your own distro. Otherwise I'm afraid those instructions are still pretty much the state of the art :-(

Answer (score 1):

I think a good start to any such endeavor is completing this project right here: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/

After doing so, most of your questions will be answered.

Comment: Installing Gentoo can be insightful as well.

Answer (score 1):

You want the **easiest** way?

http://susestudio.com/

It lets you create custom Linux VM/live-cd/live-usb through a web browser (and even run them). I'm not a suse user, but I was very impressed when I saw this in action for the first time!